# How to model a table for product identification

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am new to database modelling and learning. The book I am going through explains the model of a product database. It speaks of various product identification a product may have and how to model a database around it. I simply do not get this. Would be great if you can help me build a sample schema so that I learn.

> Goods may have various ids that are used as a standard means of
>   identifying the goods.Figure 3.3 provides a data model to identify the
>   various code or id values that a good may have. A single code may
>   uniquely identify goods and/or services, however, some goods may have
>   more than identification value.

Figure3.3
[image]

> The GOOD IDENTIFICATION entity has an attribute of ID value to store
>   the various identification codes that the good may have. The subtypes
>   of GOOD IDENTIFICATION designate the types of ids that may be given to
>   a good. The MANUFACTURER'S ID NO is a good id designated by the
>   manufacturer. The SKU (stock-keeping unit) is a standard product id
>   that distinctly identities various products. The subtype UPCA stands
>   for Universal Product Code—American and is a mechanism for identifying
>   products within America UPCE (Universal Product Code—European) is a
>   mechanism for identifying products in Europe. ISBN (International
>   Standard Book Number) is a mechanism to identify specific books
>   throughout the world. A single good may have more than one standard
>   id. For instance, a certain office supply product may have a
>   manufacturer ID number designated by the manufacturer and a UPCA
>   number identified by the industry.

Comment: Just sit down with any basic book or tutorial. It'll cover all that you need to know. Personally, I think using a term like 'good' in this context was just asking for confusion.